# Entity Framework 5, Migrations, MVC 4, update-database -force - best way to run on server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

Visual Studio MVC 4 web app, SQL Server 2008 R2, Entity Framework 5

I have automatic migrations enabled (in configuration.cs):

```
  public Configuration()
  {
     AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
     AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
  }
```

As a precaution, DataLossAllowed is disabled. What's the best way to run this migration manually, locally and on the server?

I get this error:

```
The "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method can be called only once.
```

when I try to run it from package-manager.

It seems like manually running migrations, and making them automatic are incompatible?!

Answer (score 1):

That error looks like you are initializing your database connection more than once rather than having an issue with Migrations.

`WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` is what is called when you use the `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` attribute, which in MVC4 decorates the Accounts controller by default.

As you only want this to be called once, you should remove the attribute from your Account Controller and add a call to `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` to **AuthConfig file**, which is called on application start by global.asax. You could put it straight into the application start method in global.asax or make your own file but AuthConfig seems the best place for it in my opinion.

The code for it looks like this

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DatabaseConnectionString","UserProfile","UserId","UserName", false);
```

renaming the `DatabaseConnectionString` to the name of your connection string in web.config
Also the false may be True if you are not using Db First.

Once you do that, you can remove the InitializeSimpleMembership file from the filters folder too.

This will ensure that `InitializeSimpleMembership` is only called once.

Comment: thanks - the error only happens if I run update-database. If I just run the app it's fine...

Comment: I have never tried placing the initializer in `AuthConfig file`, i have always placed it inside `Global.asax.cs`. Thanks for the option +1.

Comment: @user2254951 perform the change and see if it resolves your issue. It will prevent your initalization happening twice which is what your error message is telling you about.

Comment: sorry for the delay - it isn't in the Account Controller, but it was in filters/initializesimplemembershipattribute.cs - AND in migrations/configuration.cs (where I also have seed methods).

I removed it from filters - and now it all seems to work (which is kind of what you were alluding to?).

My original question does stand though - whats the best way to run this on the server with datalossallowed = false?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, as the question was about the exception. By run on server do you mean in live? You wouldn't use migrations on a live environment, it is handy during initial dev. If you want something for live you should look into SSDT and dacpac files. You manage your Db in VS2012 as part of your solution can can very cleanly manage DB changes in live or dev